# React- routing in two different components at a same time

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have been trying this from two days I have add Outlet also but it till not working it showing  blank page. I have routing in app.js and I want routing for dashboard page for inner page navigation for my project. I want render overview and reports in dashboard component?

index.js

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

APP.js

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './component/Home';
import Dashboard from './component/Dashboard';
import Navigation from './component/Navigation';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      App
      <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

dashboard

```
import React from 'react'
import Overview from './Overview'
import Reports from './Reports'
import { Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Dashboard</div> {/* Added the 'Dashboard' title */}
        <Link to="dashboard/">Overview</Link>
        <Link to="dashboard/reports">Reports</Link> {/* Corrected the link path */}
            
        <Routes>
          <Route path="dashboard/" element={<Overview />} />
          <Route path="dashboard/reports" element={<Reports />} />
        </Routes>
        <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```